# Display current updating time with user timezone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, timezone, timezone-offset

In my view, I have where the time is displayed for the user.

```
<h2 id="current_time">
  <%= Time.now.in_time_zone(@user.time_zone).strftime("%-I:%M:%S %p")  %>
</h2>
```

The `@user.time_zone` returns `Pacific Time (US & Canada)` and the time displays correctly. Now, I want to try and update this time using javascript so that it displays the current time if the browser is left open on this page.

Below is what I have updating the current time and this seems to work, but I cannot figure out how to get it to display in the user's time zone. It just reverts back to my system time.

How can I get this to update the `current_time` taking into account the user's time zone?

I tried passing the `@user.time_zone` to javascript, but it wants the region in `Area/Location`.

```
<script>
  var current_time = setInterval(function(){system_time()},1000);
  function system_time()
  {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("current_time").innerHTML = t;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the "t" variable as this t = ' <%= Time.now.in_time_zone(@user.time_zone).strftime("%-I:%M:%S %p")  %> ' ? Not completely sure, but it could work.

Comment: Thanks, but the ruby code would be compiled at the server and render the current time as of when it executed.